# Linq skip if not first page

Tags: c#, linq

I simply want to apply skip() to my IQueryable if a condition exist

there is a dirty solution

```
    if (currentPage!=1){
       query=query.skip(PageSize*currentPage-1)
   }
```

but I don't think this is nice and elegant code , I need something like linq whereIf extension .

how can I skip if a condition exist ? 
I am applying skip  method in  wrong way ?

the problem is if currentPage is 1  , it **should Not**  skip the first n Number of pageSize record . so I need to check the condition with if .

//elegent way   should be something like this

```
    meetings = await _meetingRepository.GetAll()
                .WhereIf(!input.IncludeCanceledMeetings,m=>!m.IsCancelled)
                .OrderBy(input.OrderBy+" " + input.Sort)
.SkipIf(input.CurrentPage!=1,input.PageSize*input.CurrentPage-1)
                .Take(input.PageSize)
                .ToListAsync();
```

thanks

Comment: Your code seems fine. You can extract it into a method (or an extension method) for more readability if you want.

Comment: Why do you believe your code is inelegant?

Comment: Something like this may work : query.Select((x,index) => new {x = x, index = index})

Comment: //elegent way                                                                                        meetings = await _meetingRepository.GetAll()
                .WhereIf(!input.IncludeCanceledMeetings,m=>!m.IsCancelled)
                .OrderBy(input.OrderBy+" " + input.Sort)
.SkipIf(input.CurrentPage!=1,input.PageSize*input.CurrentPage-1)
                .Take(input.PageSize)
                .ToListAsync();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need the condition `if (currentPage!=1)`.  You can simply write this as `query=query.skip(PageSize*(currentPage-1))`.  Lets replace the variables with constants and see what this looks like...

```
query=query.skip(10*(1-1)) // PageSize = 10, currentPage = 1
```

DO note the parenthesis (remember your order of operations from high school algebra).  1-1 = 0.  Anything multiplied by zero is zero, so the resulting code for page 1 ends up looking like this:

```
query=query.skip(0);
```

Which is substantially the same as:

```
query=query;
```

If `currentPage` was 2 instead of 1, then it would look like this:

```
query=query.skip(10*(2-1)) // == query=query.skip(10*1) == query=query.skip(10)
```

Comment: your answer is correct , i tested it before , but the problem was i was sending 0 as first page . that was miskate . i shoud had set first page as 1 .thanks

Comment: Don't forget to mark as the answer if it assisted you.